running php artisan server and it give me the phpinfo()
Whenever I try to php artisan serve and type http://127.0.0.1:8001, It returns phpinfo. Now additional confusion has it when I cancel the serve then refresh it still shows the phpinfo

I'm trying to run my project in my localhost server
i am using Laravel Framework 11.7.0

which version of laravel you are using?

Laravel Framework 11.7.0

Port 8001? Default for php artisan serve is 8000, do you have another server running? How is phpmyadmin related?

i have tried it with port 8001 it gives the issue

We know that already. When you run php artisan serve it says something like "INFO  Server running on [http://127.0.0.1:8000]." Does it say 8001 there? "when I cancel the serve" Then you should not be able to connect. If you still can connect after cancelling php artisan serve you have another server running on that port

no it shows [127.0.0.1:8000]

i have just restarted my laptop now it shows <SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)>

may be in your index file you have written echo phpinfo(); over there

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
